# Power BI - relationship ambiguity

Tags: powerbi, relationship

- I have two fact tables which I would like to connect to a dimension table (this dimension table is connected to a further dimension table).
- When I try to activate the second connection, I get an error message that this would create ambiguity between the two fact tables and that I should delete the connection between the fact tables.
- The fact tables are not connected (no relationship between them)

Error screenshot:

[image]

Data model:

[image]

How can I resolve this? It almost feels like a bug...

Comment: Check this link, i think your table relation is over-complicate, it cause it difficult to track the main reason.   https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/microsoft-power-bi/9781788290142/051a845a-b8a7-4f9f-9b20-0ab5059aa609.xhtml

Comment: It's not a bug, Try changing in your model the relationship between dim customer master and fact accounts receivable to a single direction.

Comment: @Jon: I actually already tried that but I thought, I'll try again. The difference this time is that I clicked the "Close" button on in the "Manage relationships" pop-up and that appears to materialize the change after which I opened the "Manage relationships" again and activated the second connection. Before I did it in a single take, if that makes sense... Anyway, it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Step 1: Change the relationship to fact table #1 to single direction and close relationship window so that the change materializes.
Step 2: Active second relationship between fact table #2 and dimension table.